# Horizontal lines do not print

Tags: printing, dvips, auto-pst-pdf, lmodern

I write latex documents in Article class, nothing fancy but some pstricks code and .eps pictures included.
For some reason the latex->dvips->ps2pdf routine produces .pdf files that are badly handled by the professionnal printer at work ; horizontal lines do not appear.

So I guess I need to use pdflatex, along with -shell-escape and the [auto-pst-pdf] package to produce a correct .pdf file.

Here is an exemple file.tex :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-math}
\usepackage[cleanup={log,aux,dvi,ps,pdf}]{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

Some maths : $\frac 12 + \frac 12 = 1$. A picture : 

\begin{pspicture}(-2,-1.5) (2,1.5) 
 \psset{algebraic=true,unit=1.5cm}
 \psaxes[labels=none, ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-2,-1.5) (2,1.5) 
 \psplot{-2}{2}{x^2/3} 
\end{pspicture} 

\end{document}
```

I compile this using `pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape file.tex`

However 3 issues come with this :

1. [auto-pst-pdf] creates an auxilliary -pics.pdf file, cluttering my clean folders. Any method to remove the -pics.pdf file automatically during compilation ?
2. The .pdf file created is about 10 times the size than with latex->dvips->ps2pdf, not very good for mailing purposes.
3. The compilation time is very long, also about 10 times the time of the whole latex->dvips->ps2pdf, annoying.

Any ideas to help me with those issues will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why using `auto-pst-pdf` should improve your pdf, all that means is each tikz is saved to a separate file, run through latex-dvips-ps2pdf chain you were using then the resulting pdf of each one separately included as a pdf graphic. You could try lualatex with its new direct pstricks support implemented in Lua.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. It is true that pdflatex does not seem to improve over the latex-dvips-ps2pdf chain. After a little research it appears that it does, because the dvips part included in pdflatex use the dvips -Ppdf option, which seem to increase the quality of the ps, and the pdf file created.

Comment: The pstricks processing is identical, it is just a covenience if your document is otherwise using pdflatex to run latex/dvips/ps2pdf for you in the background (you could use -Ppdf for your main document as well)

Comment: So I just tried to ditch pdflatex, and use the regular chain latex-dvips[with -Ppdf option]-ps2pdf again. It works and prints correctly. However 2 issues remain : dvips -Ppdf is very slow (20 seconds for a 10 pages documents), and the .ps file created is huge : 100MB with nothing fancy inside

Comment: try luatex ...?

Comment: Hmm, luatex not installed on my system, or not properly configured I dont know. I'd prefer to stick to regular latex for simplicity.

Comment: 20 seconds for 10 pages, I remember when 15 minutes per page was thought acceptable ...

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems I could get around all of this.

First the problem : with the usual latex->dvips->ps2pdf routine, the .pdf file created did not print correclty on a professional printer : horizontal lines did not appear.

Now the solution :

- In my case, it has to do with dvips rendering horizontal lines at a too low resolution of 600dpi.
- You can set dvips to render at a fixed resolution, says 8000dpi, via `dvips -D8000 filename.tex`
- This may make dvips very long and produce enormous .ps files of more than 100MB. This seems to be because it sometimes has to rescale some unusual fonts.
- If this is the case, try adding `\usepackage{lmodern}` to your preambule to load some fonts friendly with dvips. (The only drawback of package `lmodern` that occured is that it does not handle `\textsc` in boldface)

So basically, if some lines do not appear at printing : `latex -> dvips -D8000 filename.tex -> ps2pdf filename.ps, print filename.pdf`